# How do i do the include in User.findAll() if i have three foreign keys in the table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a user with three foreign keys. Using sequelize how do i get the details of the reference when i use findAll

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    'user',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      bank: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        references: {
          model: 'summary',
          key: 'id'
        }
      }
    },
    {
    
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'user'
    }
  );

  return User;
};
```

Loan model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Loan = sequelize.define(
    'loan',
    {
      loan_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      amoount: {
        type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
        references: {
          model: 'provider',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
   user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'user',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      guarantor_one_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'user',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      guarantor_two_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'user',
          key: 'id'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'loan'
    }
  );
  Loan.associate = models => {
    Loan.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
    Loan.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'guarantor_one_id' });
    Loan.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'guarantor_two_id' });
  };
  return Loan;
};
```

What is the best way to retrieve all the data of the user_id, guarantor_one_id and guarantor_two_id using Loan.findAll.

Thank you.

```
const loan = Loan.findAll({where : {user_id: user_id}, include: [ model: User]});
```

Its only showing only one user details in the loan, i am expecting it to return the user_id, guarantor_one_id and guarantor_two_id reference on the user table with their attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I just need to use aliases for associations in order to distinguish them from each other and then to indicate an alias (aliases) explicitly in the `include` option to help Sequelize to understand what foreign key/association to use:
**associations with aliases**

```js
  Loan.associate = models => {
    Loan.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'user' });
    Loan.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'guarantor_one_id', as: 'guarantorOne' });
    Loan.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'guarantor_two_id', as: 'guarantorTwo' });
  };
```

**usage:**

```js
const loan = Loan.findAll({
  where: {
    user_id: user_id},
    include: [{
      model: User,
      as: 'user'
    },{
      model: User,
      as: 'guarantorOne'
    },{
      model: User,
      as: 'guarantorTwo'
    }
    ]
  }
);
```